# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 11, got 1)

Tags: python, csv

I wrote a script for system automation, but I'm getting the error described in the title. My code below is the relevant portion of the script. What is the problem?

```
import csv
import os

DIR = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/key_list.csv"

def Customer_List(csv):
    customer = open(DIR)
        for line in customer:
            row = []
            (row['MEM_ID'],
             row['MEM_SQ'],
             row['X_AUTH_USER'],
             row['X_AUTH_KEY'],
             row['X_STORAGE_URL'],
             row['ACCESSKEY'],
             row['ACCESSKEYID'],
             row['ACCESSKEY1'],
             row['ACCESSKEYID1'],
             row['ACCESSKEY2'],
             row['ACCESSKEYID2'])=line.split()
            if csv == row['MEM_ID']:
                customer.close()
                return(row)
            else:
                print ("Not search for ID")
                return([])

id_input = input("Please input the Customer ID(Email): ")
result = Customer_List(id_input)

if result:
    print ("iD:    " + id['MEM_ID']
```

Comment: 99% chance: there's an empty line somewhere.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 initially the OP pasted his code. Since he was new he did to indent it properly it was mess. So I think he thought he could past a picture which not be messy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the line

```
line.split()
```

What are you splitting on? Looks like a CSV, so try

```
line.split(',')
```

Example:

```
"one,two,three".split()  # returns one element ["one,two,three"]
"one,two,three".split(',')  # returns three elements ["one", "two", "three"]
```

As @TigerhawkT3 mentions, it would be better to use the CSV module. Incredibly quick and easy method available [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

Comment: Oddly, the OP imports the `csv` module but never uses it (and even masks the import within the function). I'd lean more towards using a proper `csv.reader` rather than using a different `str.split()`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 agreed. Linked to documentation.

Comment: @Mr.Sharp I think your CSV has only 10 fields in it, so your error now must be `(expected 11, got 10)`. Make sure that you are assigning an equal amount of fields from the right side of the `=` to the left.

Answer (score 5):

The error message is fairly self-explanatory

```
(a,b,c,d,e) = line.split()
```

expects `line.split()` to yield 5 elements, but in your case, it is only yielding 1 element. This could be because the data is not in the format you expect, a rogue malformed line, or maybe an empty line - there's no way to know.

To see what line is causing the issue, you could add some debug statements like this:

```
if len(line.split()) != 11:
    print line
```

As Martin suggests, you might also be splitting on the wrong delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is wrong with your data, it isn't in the format you are expecting. It could be a new line character or a blank space in the data that is tinkering with your code.